# Как правильно выделить методы?

Tags: java, ооп, рефакторинг

Как правильно разделить следующую программу на методы:

```
import java.util.Date;
import static java.lang.Math.*;

public class lab1{

    public static void main (String[] S) {
        System.out.println("Date");
        Date d=new Date();
        System.out.printf(" %1$tT\n",d);
        double x = 0.335;
        double y = 0.225;
        double s;
        double f;

        s=1+x+pow(x,2)/2+pow(x,3)/6+pow(x,4)/24;
        f=x*(pow(sin(x),3)+pow(Math.cos(y),2));
        System.out.println(s);
        System.out.println(f);
    }
```

}

Comment: Такую замечательную, маленькую линейную программку **не надо** делить. От этого она станет только хуже (менее понятной). 

Выделение вывода в отдельные методы здесь приведет только к росту количества строчек. В остальных местах вообще нет общих частей, которые было бы логично написать отдельно.

Короче, программа слишком мала и тривиальна для упражнений по ООП.

Comment: Ничего подобного. Разделение на методы улучшит её читаемость. А в током виде это просто каша. Но действительно, ООП тут и не пахнет.

Comment: Для улучшения читаемости я оставил бы x и y, а весь вывод разместил в одном отформатированном printf().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> class lab1{

вот тема вопроса =)
 он у тебя хоть компилится?)

```
public double powMethod(double x) {
return s=1+x+Math.pow(x,2)/2+Math.pow(x,3)/6+Math.pow(x,4)/24; }
 System.out.println(powMethod);
```

2й попробуй самА сделать

Comment: админ поправил тему, вопрос(задачка) - вообще пропал =)

Comment: По-моему это бред)))
С точки зрения синтаксиса...

Answer (score 2):

Теоретически у вас должно быть что-то вроде этого:

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Lab1
{

   public static void main ( final String [] S )
   {
      System.out.println ( "Date" );

      printFormatted ( new Date () );

      final double x = 0.335;
      final double y = 0.225;

      final double s = calculateS ( x );
      final double f = calculateF ( x, y );

      printResults ( s, f );
   }

   private static double calculateF ( final double x, final double y )
   {
      return x * ( Math.pow ( Math.sin ( x ), 3 ) + Math.pow ( Math.cos ( y ), 2 ) );
   }

   private static double calculateS ( final double x )
   {
      return 1 + x + Math.pow ( x, 2 ) / 2 + Math.pow ( x, 3 ) / 6 + Math.pow ( x, 4 ) / 24;
   }

   private static void printFormatted ( final Date date )
   {
      System.out.printf ( " %1$tT\n", date );
   }

   private static void printResults ( final double s, final double f )
   {
      System.out.println ( s );
      System.out.println ( f );
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Метод:

```
public static double powMethod(double x) {
    double s = 1+x+Math.pow(x,2)/2+Math.pow(x,3)/6+Math.pow(x,4)/24;
    return s;
}
```

Его вызов и вывод результата на экран:

```
System.out.println(powMethod(1.2));
```

Аналогично для второй длинной строки.